# How to attch view with Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

i am trying to implement a screen that has reverse recyclerview. New items are being added from bottom, but i have a imageview on top of recyclerview. Here is what i want to achieve.[image]

When new item is added, imageview should move too. How can i achieve this? Should i use coordinator layout? Thanks in advance for your response

Comment: use retaive layout as parent. now set recyclerview height wrap_content and set it as alignparent_bottom=true, and set image view above=recyclerviewID

Comment: -Thanks a lot, i thought more complex :D It works, thanks again

Comment: What about placing `ImageView` as the first item of your `RecyclerView`?

Comment: I thought about it but at some point i have to move image view to top of screen. I will add a transition so this solution will not work for me. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the new android ViewGroup `ConstraintLayout`.
From official doc:

> It's similar to `RelativeLayout` in that all views are laid out according to relationships between sibling views and the parent layout, but it's more flexible than `RelativeLayout` and easier to use with Android Studio's Layout Editor.

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

1. Compile the dependence: `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`
2. Build your layout ;)

Layout example for your case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recycler_view"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have never use ConstraintLayout but i will try